# Place Parenthesis Around Final Count in Batch File Output

Tags: batch-file

First off, I have absolutely no experience writing code, but I do like to use batch files to accomplish various tasks and have many that I use on a regular basis.

I don't know if this topic has been brought up on a forum before, so excuse me in advance if it has.

My dilemma is, I have a batch file that is working great for me, but I need to have a parenthesis around the final number count.

The following is the code within the batch file:

```
 @echo off

 FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO (
     PUSHD "%%G"
     FOR /F "delims=" %%H in ('dir /a-d /b * ^|find /C /V ""') DO echo %%G %%H>>"..\count.txt"
     POPD
 )
```

Let's say I have a folder named: **Colors**
and within the Colors folder are three sub-folders named: **Red**, **Blue**, and **Green**.

When I paste the batch file into the Colors folder and run it, I get a text file named "count" that reads as follows when it's opened:

Blue 31
Green 25
Red 33

I'm needing it to end up as:

Blue (31)
Green (25)
Red (33)

Can someone please help me?

Comment: So what is stopping you form putting them in the echo command? You also do not need the `PUSHD` and `POPD` if you just change your directory listing to `dir /a-d /b "%%G\*"`

Comment: Just one big long line: `FOR /D %%G in ("*") DO FOR /F "delims=" %%H in ('dir /a-d /b "%%G\"* 2^>nul ^|find /C /V ""') DO echo %%G (%%H)>>"count.txt"`. If you use your existing code you need to escape the right parentheses.

Comment: Or you could go for this single line [tag:batch-file] instead, `@(For /F "EOL=?Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B/AD 2^>NUL')Do @For /F %%H In ('XCopy "%%G" ? /HILQ')Do @Echo %%G (%%H^))>"count.txt"`

Comment: Thanks for your help Squashman. I chose the "just one big long line" approach and it works just the way I need it to. Thanks again!